# Bind nginx VPS to domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns

I've installed [Nginx,PHP, Laravel framework](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) on a VPS (ubuntu). now i am going to bind my domain to that vps. I've set `server_name mydomain.com;` in Nginx config . I've also set my VPS IP in domain DNS panel .
[image]

what else should i do?
somewhere i read about installing [`bind`](https://crm.vpscheap.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=10) , but im not sure if it is needed for my case.

Comment: No, you don't need bind, this should be enough.

Comment: so what could be  wrong? if i ping my domain :`Ping request could not find host MYDOMAIN.com. Please check the name and try again.` I've also installed `bind` but i stopped it

Comment: Well, if you provide real domain name, we can check. You can try [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/www.example.com@8.8.8.8) if it resolves correctly

Comment: @DusanBajic may i have your email ?